# Visual C++ setting to insert a newline at end of file

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, g++

While compiling C++ code that is cross platform, g++ throws a compiler error if a .cpp or .h file does not have a newline at its end. Is there a visual studio setting that would do this automatically?

Comment: Hahaha, nearly 5 years later and it still isn't possible out of the box...

Comment: @nevelis Maybe its a problem of a compiler?

Comment: @flamingo What does a compiler have to do with formatting??

Comment: @nevelis It doesn't. But why it throws an error when a file doesn't have a newline? That's what I meant.

Comment: @flamingo A preprocessor takes a file and includes it verbatim.  If there's no newline at the bottom of the file, it's possible that the first line of the next file being processed gets glued to the last line of the previous.

GCC & VS work around this, but older compilers aren't so robust, so cross-platform code should cope with this.  The warning is to help prevent you writing code that doesn't work on older compilers.

Every text editor I can think of except Notepad & VS adds, or can be configured to add, a newline at the end of each file on save :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a plugin like Visual Assist or something to create code templates that put newlines at the end of your file in addition to niceties like header guards and such.

Answer (score -1):

No. Why not simply leave out a couple of lines at the end when you start working on the file?